# is it possible to extract concatenated values from json using JsonPath

Tags: c#, json, .net, json.net, jsonpath

is it possible to extract concatenated values from JSON using JSONPath? I want to get addresses from JSON array property as complete address lists.

Here is my JSON input. It looks like

```
{"quoteSummary": {"result": [{"address": "One Apple Park Way","city": "Cupertino"},{"address": "Microsoft","city": "New York"}]}}
```

If I run the code below

```
var jsonString = @"{ ""quoteSummary"": { ""result"": [ { ""address1"": ""One Apple Park Way"", ""city"": ""Cupertino"" }, { ""address1"": ""Microsoft"", ""city"": ""New York"" } ] } }";
var data = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
var SelectStrings = data.SelectTokens("quoteSummary.result..['address1','city']");
```

I received output as `["One Apple Park Way", "Cupertino", "Microsoft", "New York"]`

But I want like `["One Apple Park Way , Cupertino", "Microsoft , New York"]`

Note: this JSON path won't work in [Json Path Evaluator](https://jsonpath.com/) but work with Visual Studio.

I tried using (address & ' ' & city)

Comment: var json= @"{
                              ""quoteSummary"": {
                                ""result"": [
                                  {
                                      ""address1"": ""One Apple Park Way"",
                                      ""city"": ""Cupertino""
                                  },
{
                                      ""address1"": ""Microsoft"",
                                      ""city"": ""New York""
                                  }
                                ]
                              }
                            }";

Comment: Json.NET's  JSONPath  implementation does not support a `Concat()` operator.  You can check the [`QueryOperator` enum in the source code](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JsonPath/QueryExpression.cs#L19) for all supported operators; there's nothing resembling `Concat()`.

Comment: That being said, do you need a pure JSONPath solution?  Or would a JSONPath + LINQ combined solution be acceptable?

Comment: `Concat()` isn't part of JSON Path.  Probably why Json.Net doesn't support it.

Comment: I need pure json path solutions as it will be configuration for each of entity type, And i am using "Newtonsoft.Json" , "Newtonsoft.Json.Linq"

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible with Json.NET's implementation of JSONPath as shown in my answer.  You will need to change your requirements, or switch to a different solution.  For instance [Jayway JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) for Java implements [`concat(X)`](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#functions).  Or you could fork Json.NET's [JsonPath](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/tree/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JsonPath) directory and implement it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

As of Json.NET [13.0.3](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/13.0.3) it is not possible to extract concatenated values from JSON purely via a JSONPath query, because Json.NET's JSONPath  implementation does not support a `concat()` function.  You can check the [`QueryOperator` enum in the source code](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JsonPath/QueryExpression.cs#L19) for all supported operators; there's nothing resembling `concat()`.<sup>[1]</sup>

You will need to change your requirements, or switch to a different solution.  For instance [Jayway JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) for Java implements [`concat(X)`](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#functions).  Or you could fork Json.NET's [JsonPath](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/tree/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JsonPath) directory and implement it yourself.

As one alternative, if you are willing to change your requirements, you could combine a JSONPath query with a LINQ [`Select()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select) projection as follows:

```
var selectStrings = data
    .SelectTokens("quoteSummary.result[*]") // Select all quoteSummary.result objects
    .Select(o => string.Join(" , ", o["address1"], o["city"])) // And join the address1 and city properties of each into a string
    .ToList(); // And materialize into a list of strings.
```

Which results in

```json
["One Apple Park Way , Cupertino","Microsoft , New York"]
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MyaweU).

---

<sup>[1]</sup> At the time of this answer, [13.0.3](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/13.0.3) is the most recently released Json.NET version.  It supports the following [operators](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/13.0.3/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JsonPath/QueryExpression.cs#L16):

> ```
> internal enum QueryOperator
> {
>     None = 0,
>     Equals = 1,
>     NotEquals = 2,
>     Exists = 3,
>     LessThan = 4,
>     LessThanOrEquals = 5,
>     GreaterThan = 6,
>     GreaterThanOrEquals = 7,
>     And = 8,
>     Or = 9,
>     RegexEquals = 10,
>     StrictEquals = 11,
>     StrictNotEquals = 12
> }
> ```

As you can see, there's no `concat()`.  In fact Json.NET's JSONPath implementation doesn't support any functions like those from [Jayway JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#functions), for confirmation see the related issues:

- [Unable to use JSONPath expressions like @.length #1318](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1318)
- [length not working when we run jsonpath query with SelectTokens #2688](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/2688)
- [JSONPath not found expressions like min, max, length #2816](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/2816)

Comment: I need pure json path solution

Comment: @pankajagarwal - You did not state this requirement when you asked your question.  But if this is the requirement, then as documented in my answer, you cannot use Json.NET's implementation of JSONPath.  You must either change your requirements, switch to a different JSONPath implementation, or implement it yourself by forking Json.NET's implementation.